# Certbot SAN not working on migration to Google Cloud from AWS

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, certbot

I'm migrating an ubuntu/Wordpress/Apache2 server (22.04LTS) from AWS to Google Cloud. We host multiple domains from this server and use Certbot to manage certificates. On the AWS instance, I'd just generate a certificate with all domains in it, and it would work perfectly. On GC, it simply will not recognise all the domains in a certificate. E.g.

highland.photography + [www.highland.photography](http://www.highland.photography) works fine
the above + richardharr.is and [www.richardharr.is](http://www.richardharr.is) doesn't - the last two domains just aren't recognised as having a valid certificate.

Certbot v2.8.0 and, as noted, is working perfectly on AWS.

I'm assuming its a SAN/Rewrite issue, but I've actually tried to clone all configs as much as possible.

---

My point was that on the AWS instance, a single certificate for multiple domains worked perfectly, with no question from any browser. What I'm trying therefore to work out is why there's a difference between the systems.

Comment: Do not use one certificate with a bunch of domains. That makes you look like an amateur and the sites suspicious. Create separate virtual hosts and a certificate per virtual host primary domain. Regarding the problem that you posted, you have not provided enough details to suggest anything. Note: do not blindly copy Let's Encrypt configuration files from one server to another.

Comment: You have updated the question without providing any details on your web server, Let's Encrypt, logs, debugging steps, configuration, etc.